# Read or generate thumbnail from selected asset in unreal engine

Tags: python, thumbnails, blueprint, unreal-engine5

i’m currently working on a file browser that can read uasset thumbnails. I’ve got a python script, which can access the selected assets in the content browser, but I don’t know how to read or generate a thumbnail out of the asset object.
For now I want to read a thumbnail from an asset and save it as a png file on the desktop for example. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.